# I have 3 virtual servers with a lot of storage - can I use the storage in a reliable way somehow?

Tags: kubernetes

Here's the deal:

I have 3 virtual servers (K8S worker nodes) with 160 GB of virtual SSD each. They form together a private network and I would like to utilize the space for persistent volume claims.

Preferably in a way similar to RAID 1 or RAID 5.

Installing rook.io is not possible because it's not bare metal.

Is there some way to have "RAID over NFS" or something in K8S? I'm running RKE.

Comment: You may draw reference from this [Stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344789/make-raid-over-nfs)

Comment: check out longhorn https://longhorn.io/, something similar but not exactly raid.

Comment: GlusteFS, Ceph - don't think rook only works on bare metal - but not so sure.